# How can I optimize upsert batch query in mongodb with 1M records

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a script that is constantly downloading data, I am saving that data into MongoDB.
There is an Id associated with each document. 
If I receive the same document, I just update one part. 
If the id is new I add the whole document.

Now the problem is when there are no documents in MongoDB, it runs smoothly, but when I have about 30k documents in mongo, the performance starts degrading.

```
var batch = database_object.collection(channel_basic_data_collection).initializeUnorderedBulkOp({useLegacyOps: true}); 
batch.find(query).upsert().updateOne(update_OPERTATION);

if (count > 1000 ) 
{ 
  batch.execute(function (err, result) {

                    if (err){
                        errorLog(err)
                        operation_started = false
                        return
                    }

                    batch = database_object.collection(channel_basic_data_collection).initializeUnorderedBulkOp({useLegacyOps: true});
});

}
```

I need to insert 1.5M documents and for every new document, I need to search the whole collection.

Answer (score 0):

Create an [index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/) in the fields you're using to query.

Comment: indexing creates overburden upon writing. Already tried it on "id" field as well.